# selecting the Row of table Except the First one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i want to select all the row except the Top One so can anybody help me on this Query.

Comment: How's the "top one" defined - actually, which query????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
with cte as
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by CustomerId) RowNumber
    from Sales.Customer
)
select *
from cte
where RowNumber != 1
```

OR

```
select *
from
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by CustomerId) RowNumber
    from Sales.Customer
) tt
where RowNumber != 1
```

Comment: **with cte as
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by loan_issue_id) RowNumber
    from dbo.loan_issue_mcg
)
select *
from cte
where RowNumber != 1 and loan_id=1170 ** this one still shows all the row

Comment: @Dinup kandel - add `where loan_id=1170` inside of `cte`

Comment: @Dinup kandel - with cte as ( select *, row_number() over (order by loan_issue_id) RowNumber from dbo.loan_issue_mcg where loan_id=1170) select * from cte where RowNumber != 1

Answer (score 7):

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this:

```sql
select * from TableName order by Id offset 1 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` attribute is known than we can use..

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id
  FROM table 
  LIMIT 1
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```