# select all rows except top row

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

how do I return all rows from a table except the first row.  Here is my sql statement:

```
Select Top(@TopWhat) * 
from tbl_SongsPlayed 
where Station = @Station 
order by DateTimePlayed DESC
```

How do I alter my SQL statement to return all rows except the first row.

Many thanks

Comment: did you google?i just copied the title and search and found so many answers! here is one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027125/selecting-the-row-of-table-except-the-first-one

Comment: what version of sql server?

Answer (score 32):

SQL 2012 also has the rather handy OFFSET clause:

```
Select Top(@TopWhat) *
from tbl_SongsPlayed 
where Station = @Station 
order by DateTimePlayed DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS
```

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your database product, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from
(
  Select s.*,
    row_number() over(order by DateTimePlayed DESC) rn
  from tbl_SongsPlayed s
  where s.Station = @Station 
) src
where rn >1
```

Answer (score 1):

The EXCEPT operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
Select Top(@TopWhat) *
from tbl_SongsPlayed 
Except  Select Top(1) *
from tbl_SongsPlayed 
where Station = @Station 
order by DateTimePlayed DESC
```

'Not In' was another clause that can be used.

Comment: The first subquery is neither filtered nor ordered. The result of the complete query may not be what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique ID for `tbl_SongsPlayed`, you could do something like this:

```
// Filter the songs first
With SongsForStation
As   (
   Select *
   From   tbl_SongsPlayed
   Where  Station = @Station
)
// Get the songs
Select *
From   SongsForStation
Where  SongPlayId <> (
   // Get the top song, most recently played, so you can exclude it.
   Select Top 1 SongPlayId
   From   SongsForStation
   Order By DateTimePlayed Desc
   )
// Sort the rest of the songs.
Order By
   DateTimePlayed desc
        Where
```