# How to skip the first row of data in SQL Query?

Tags: excel, vba, qsqlquery

I have this code:

select DOLFUT from [DATABASE $]

How do I get it to get data from the 2nd line? (skip only the first line of data and collect all the rest)

Comment: It looks like this question has been asked already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032803/select-all-rows-except-top-row/15032884

Comment: how are you defining "first one"? you arent even ordering by anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL skip first 10 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827029/mysql-skip-first-10-results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LIMIT to skip any number of row you want. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10
```

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

> With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

[MySql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't available in MS Access - since the OP has marked this answer as the solution, perhaps this question is tagged incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In *Access*, which you seem to use, you can use:

```sql
Select DOLFUT 
From [DATABASE $] 
Where DOLFUT Not In
    (Select Top 1 T.DOLFUT 
    From [DATABASE $] As T 
    Order By 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data in tables have no inherent order.

> *To get  data from the 2nd line*

, you have to set up some sort sequence and then bypass the first record of the set - as Gustav has shown.